# Putnam 2012 - Exercise B.4 - Alternative solution check

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, contest-math

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

*Suppose that $a_0 = 1$ and that $a_{n+1} = a_n + e^{-a_n}$ for $n=0,1,2,\dots$. Does $a_n - \log n$
have a finite limit as $n \to \infty$?*

---

**MY SOLUTION**

We can show in fact that $(a_n-\log n)$ is a **null sequence**.

1. $(a_n)$ is monototonically increasing, and thus has a limit. Suppose it is finite and equal to $\alpha$. Then $(a_{n+1}-a_n) \to 0$. But we have $(a_{n+1}-a_{n})\to e^{-\alpha}$, a contradiction. So $(a_n) \to \infty$.
2. Let $b_n = e^{a_n}$. Then \begin{eqnarray}\lim_{n\to \infty} (b_{n+1}-b_n) &=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(e^{a_{n+1}}-e^{a_n}\right)=\\ &=& \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(e^{a_n+e^{-a_n}}-e^{a_n}\right)=\\&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{e^{-a_n}}-1}{e^{-a_n}}=1.\end{eqnarray}
3. By Cesaro-Stolz Theorem we have therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}{n} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{e^{a_n}}n = 1.$$ Hence $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\log\frac{e^{a_n}}{n} = 0$$ and the thesis follows.

---

**QUESTION**

I haven't found this approach in other solutions online, but is seems to me quite straightforward. Is it fine?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Maybe this is similar to the second solution [here](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2012s.pdf)? After all, Cesaro-Stolz is a discrete version of L'Hopital which is nothing but Taylor's expansion.

Comment: It looks correct to me. +1